# Changing classes on dynamic button

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I use a service called crossrider which basically is an api for producing browser extensions.

To install the extension their JS generates a button which does not fit my site design and am trying to change it.

This is what it generates:

```
<div id="crossriderInstallButton">
    <a sl-processed="1" style="color:white;font-size:1em" class="crossrider_button crossrider_button_blue crossrider_button_medium" href="javascript://">Install Now</a>
</div>
```

I'm waiting for the page to load and then want to simply change classes but nothing happens.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.crossrider_button').removeClass('crossrider_button_blue crossrider_button_medium').addClass('btn btn-info');
});
```

**UPDATE - RESOLVED**

```
$(window).load(function(){ // <-- correct way to wait until page fully loaded
    $('.crossrider_button').removeClass('crossrider_button_blue crossrider_button_medium').addClass('btn btn-info');
});
```

Comment: How often does it generate it??

Comment: $(document).ready() != window.onload

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy4X/

Answer (score 1):

try writing the code in **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)**.It will Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need remove main class crossrider_button too, try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.crossrider_button').removeClass('crossrider_button crossrider_button_blue crossrider_button_medium').addClass('btn btn-info');
});
```